# Cracking an appliance's network protocol

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis, cbc, blocksize

I'm trying to crack my thermostat's network protocol.
I've captured several rounds of network traffic and here is what I've got to work with.

- Communicating via HTTP POST
- The POST data is JSON followed by ciphertext.
- The JSON contains:

  - A device unique id: 48 bits
  - An eiv (initialization vector?): 128 bits
- The minimum ciphertext length is 32 bytes.
- The ciphertext length is always a multiple of 16 bytes
- A shared secret key: 32 bits
- It's likely that many of ciphertexts have the same plaintext.
- The thermostat has very limited computing resources.

I know that AES CBC would produce cipher text of those lengths.
What other encryption schemes might produce this type of output?

Assuming it's AES is there away to detect what the key size is?
What are the common ways a 32 bit secret is expanded to 128 bits?